# How to show touch area of image view will be bright remaining part of image view will be black and white in android

Tags: android, imageview

I am developing one application. In that focus on specific part of image view. when touch any where of image view that part of image view will be bright remaining part of image view will be black and white. Means focus particular part of image view. How can i do this. any one can tell me how can i do this.. Am sending one code how to move inner rect on imageview when touch on imageview.. please can anyone tell me....

```
  Imageview.java:



*public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 Button btnLoadImage,save;;
 ImageView imageResult;
 final int RQS_IMAGE1 = 1;
 Uri source;
 Bitmap bitmapMaster;
 Canvas canvasMaster;
 Bitmap bitmapResult;
 int x = 0;
 int y =0;
int r =0;
RelativeLayout rel;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loadimage);
    save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    imageResult = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    rel=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.realtive);
    btnLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_IMAGE1);
        }
    });
    imageResult.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "touch", 1000).show();
            int w = bitmapMaster.getWidth();
            int h = bitmapMaster.getHeight();
            RectF rectF = new RectF(w/4, h/4, w*3/4, h*3/4);

            float blurRadius = 40.0f;
            bitmapResult = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvasResult = new Canvas(bitmapResult);

            Paint blurPaintInner = new Paint();
            blurPaintInner.setColor(0xFFffffff);
            blurPaintInner.setMaskFilter(new 
                    BlurMaskFilter(blurRadius, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.OUTER));
            canvasResult.drawRect(rectF, blurPaintInner);

            loadGrayBitmap(bitmapMaster);
            //imageResult.setImageBitmap(bitmapResult);
            return true;
        }
    });

    save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            store();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "image saved", 1000).show();

        }
    });
 }
 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case RQS_IMAGE1:
            source = data.getData();
            try {
                bitmapMaster = BitmapFactory
                        .decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                                source));
                loadGrayBitmap(bitmapMaster);
                imageResult.setImageBitmap(bitmapResult);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
  }
  /*public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        x = (int) event.getX();
        y = (int) event.getY();
        r = 20;
        undonePaths.clear();
        mPath.reset();
        // Atlast invalidate canvas

        break;
    }
    return true;
   }*/
 private void loadGrayBitmap(Bitmap src) {
    if (src != null) {
        int w = src.getWidth();
        int h = src.getHeight();
        RectF rectF = new RectF(w/4, h/4, w*3/4, h*3/4);

        float blurRadius = 100.0f;
        bitmapResult = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvasResult = new Canvas(bitmapResult);
        Paint blurPaintOuter = new Paint();
        blurPaintOuter.setColor(0xFFffffff);
        blurPaintOuter.setMaskFilter(new 
                BlurMaskFilter(blurRadius, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.INNER));
        canvasResult.drawBitmap(bitmapMaster, 0, 0, blurPaintOuter);
        Paint blurPaintInner = new Paint();
        blurPaintInner.setColor(0xFFffffff);
        blurPaintInner.setMaskFilter(new 
                BlurMaskFilter(blurRadius, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.OUTER));
        canvasResult.drawRect(rectF, blurPaintInner);
        //canvasResult.drawCircle(cx, cy, radius, paint)


        imageResult.setImageBitmap(bitmapResult);
    }
    }
   public void store()
   { 
    String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File mFolder = new File(extr + "/blur");
    if (!mFolder.exists()) {
        mFolder.mkdir();
    }
    String strF = mFolder.getAbsolutePath();
   // File mSubFolder = new File(strF + "/MyApp-SubFolder");
   /* if (!mSubFolder.exists()) {
        mSubFolder.mkdir();
    }*/
    rel.getRootView();
    rel.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap m=rel.getDrawingCache();
    String s = "myfile.png";

   File f = new File(mFolder.getAbsolutePath()+mFolder.separator+ "IMG_"+String
            .valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())+".png");

    String strMyImagePath = f.getAbsolutePath();
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        m.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,70, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
    }*



  xml:


*<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:autoLink="web"

    android:textStyle="bold" />
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/loadimage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Image" />

  <RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/realtive"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    > 

  <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/result"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />

     </RelativeLayout>
    <Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/realtive"
     android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
     android:text="save" />
    </RelativeLayout>*
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:-

```
<ImageButton 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@null"
android:src="@drawable/your_Image"
/>
```

If this is not a right solution for your problem than please put your code here so i can take look of your exact problem.

Spartacus thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageButton 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@null"
android:scaleType="center"
android:src="@drawable/your_Image"
/>
```

Use above and on click just change the background of image button to look blur.
This may work Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. But am touch any where in the dynamic gallery image view that part will be bright and remaining will be blur....

Comment: can you share the image how you want it to look.Thanks